# C++,class, a function that returns an object

Tags: c++, function, class

I wrote a Class called `Point` and want to write a function that takes 2 `Points` and sum them.

why I should write it as the following:

```
Point SumPoints(Point& p1, Point& p2)
{
    Point result(p1->x + p2->x, p1->y + p2->y);
    return result;
}
```

won't it be more efficient to define a pointer the the result and return it?
(instead of defining a new Point 'result' and then copying it again in main)

Plus, I'm a little bit confused about when the copy function is being called automatically? is that true that whenever I type `=` it will be called?

Comment: Do you want to return a pointer to a local variable?

Comment: Why should `=` cause an addition? If anything `+` should cause an addition, but for this, you need to overload `operator+(const Point&, const Point&)`

Answer (score 0):

Here, it is perfectly valid to return `result` by value. Modern compilers will apply NRVO [named return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) such that no copying is required. It would be more confusing if a pointer is returned by a sum operation.

Regarding you other question (if I got that correctly), using `=` does not always involve copying. For instance, there is also a move assignment operator which simply moves an `rvalue` reference into an object instead of copy it. There are also cases where copy elision applies (same link as above) and allows to completely avoid copy and move semantics.

In the following example you can see that copying or moving is mostly omitted by the compiler ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9XzJA8))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct Point{ 
    Point() = default;
    Point(double x, double y):x(x),y(y){}

    Point(const Point &p):x(p.x),y(p.y){
        std::cout << "copy construct" << std::endl;}

    Point(Point&& p):x(std::move(p.x)),y(std::move(p.y)){
        std::cout << "move construct" << std::endl;}

    Point& operator=(const Point& p){
        x = p.x; 
        y = p.y; 
        std::cout << "copy assign" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    Point& operator=(Point&& p){
        x = std::move(p.x); 
        y = std::move(p.y); 
        std::cout << "move assign" << std::endl; 
        return *this;
    }
    double x,y;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point& p)
{
    out << std::setw(5) << p.x << std::setw(5) << p.x << std::flush;
    return out;
}

Point operator+(const Point& p1, const Point &p2)
{
    return Point(p1.x+p2.x,p1.y+p2.y);
}

Point sum1(const Point& p1, const Point &p2)
{
    return Point(p1.x+p2.x,p1.y+p2.y);
}

Point sum2(const Point& p1, const Point &p2)
{
    Point result;
    result.x = p1.x+p2.x;
    result.y = p1.y+p2.y;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Point p1(1,0), p2(0,1);
    auto r1 = sum2(p1,p2);
    auto r2 = sum1(p1,p2);
    auto r3 = r1+r2; 
    auto r4 = r3; // <- only this calls the copy constructor

    std::cout << "r3 = ("<< r3 << ")"<< std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
copy construct
r3 = (    2    2)
```

As a hint, you can overload the `+` operator as shown in the example to write the summation in a more readable way.

Comment: I read that article but still confused, how could the compiler take the value and save it to another Point without copying data...

Comment: @smith There is no other value. The compiler constructs the point directly in the place where it's needed.

Comment: @smith If the compiler is asked to return a copy to temporary, it might simply give you the temporary instead. Why should it copy data from one place to another just to immediately delete the source object immediatly afterwards. Therefore, copying is omitted, you still get a value returned as promised by the function, everyone's happy. I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> won't it be more efficient to define a pointer the the result and return it?

If you don't create an object, then there wouldn't be anything for the pointer to point to.

It would also be highly confusing and un-conventional to return a pointer from addition operator.

> and then copying it again in main

It won't necessarily be copied at all if the optimiser manages to elide the copy.

If you're initialising an object with the result rather than assigning, you can make sure that there won't be a copy by returning a prvalue:

```
return Point(p1->x + p2->x, p1->y + p2->y);
```

Comment: why "return Point(p1->x + p2->x, p1->y + p2->y);" is better than the first method in my post, should I always use it?, and how it is ever possible that there won't be a copy?

Comment: @smith `how it is ever possible that there won't be a copy?` Because that is the way language is specified. The object is simply initialised using the prvalue epression  that was used in the return statement rather than being initialised from a temporary object. `should I always use it` You should prefer prvalues when you can use them and when it is important to avoid copying.